# SELECT AS column does not exist in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

I am using Postgres to select values from a relation in my database. I would like to have additional columns that do not exist in the original relation, so I achieve this using a query similar to the one below:

```
SELECT table1.*, table1.title || table1.first_name || table1.last_name AS full_name, table2.email AS user_email FROM (table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id) WHERE table1.type = 'Open' AND user_email ILIKE '%test%';
```

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
error: column "user_email" does not exist
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the specified alias directly in the `WHERE` clause.

You can use the original column name instead:

```
WHERE table1.type = 'Open' AND table2.emailILIKE '%test%';
```