# In SQL, why can't I use the other queries in SELECT statement to do calculation?

Tags: sql, column-alias

Here's the sample table 'test0608':

```
product_name     color        amount
Product1         Red             123
Product1         Blue             126
Product2         Blue             103
Product2         Red             NULL
Product2         Red             89
Product1         Red             203
```

I'm trying to find all products with red ones more than blue ones. And here's my code:

```
        select 
         product_name
         ,sum(case when color = Blue then 1 else 0 end ) as blue_num 
         ,sum(case when color = Red then 1 else 0 end ) as red_num 
         ,(red_num- blue_num) as difference
         
         from test0608   
         group by product_name
```

However, I get the error 'Unknown column 'red_num' and 'blue_num'' which means I CAN'T use the two sums I just calculated in the select statement. Why?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: For Postgres see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603783/select-as-column-does-not-exist-in-where-clause or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392048/cant-find-column-alias-in-case-with-order-by-in-postgres

Comment: You cant use it like that. It is not allowed. See the below answers for alternatives

Comment: You need single quotes around string constants.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this. blue_num and red_num are alias here. So it is not used here as a field.

```
SELECT  product_name
     , SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blue_num 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS red_num 
     , (SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS difference
FROM test0608   
GROUP BY product_name;
```

Alternate way by using subquery. if want to show **positive** difference of red_num then use red_num >= blue_num in **WHERE** clause. But if show all product but **negative** difference is 0 then USE **CASE WHEN t.red_num >= t.blue_num THEN t.red_num - t.blue_num ELSE 0 END** difference

```
SELECT t.product_name
     , t.blue_num
     , t.red_num
     , (t.red_num - t.blue_num) AS difference
FROM (SELECT product_name
           , SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blue_num 
           , SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS red_num
      FROM test0608   
      GROUP BY product_name) t;
```

Comment: Can also be written as `SUM(CASE color WHEN 'Red' THEN 1 WHEN 'Blue' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) as difference`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no order in which the DBMS must evaluate the columns in a `SELECT` clause. The DBMS may try to evaluate `difference` before `blue_num`.

Hence alias names that you create in the `SELECT` clause are only known afterwards, i.e. in the `ORDER BY` clause and the query result. They can not be used inside the `SELECT` clause itself.

(Additional remark: Contrary to standard SQL, MySQL and PostgreSQL allow using the column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause, too.)