# Combine single values from different select statements using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two distinct queries which return single values and I would like to combine them into one single value. See below:

Query 1:

```
select sum(value)
    from table.trans as transactions
    where country= 'UK' 
    and transactions.from = 'Angela'
```

Query 2:

```
select sum(value)
    from table.trans as transactions
    where country= 'UK' 
    and transactions.to= 'Angela'
```

I now want to get:

```
 Value from query 1 - Value from query 2
```

Comment: `TO` and `FROM` are MySQL reserved words (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). They need to be delimited using back-ticks.

Comment: @AdamB. You'll get similar answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842484/in-sql-why-cant-i-use-the-other-queries-in-select-statement-to-do-calculation/68842509?noredirect=1#comment121667571_68842509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when t.to = 'Angela' then value end) as to_value,
       sum(case when t.from = 'Angela' then value end) as from_value
from table.trans t
where country = 'UK' and 'Angela' in (t.to, t.from);
```

For the difference:

```
select sum(case when t.to = 'Angela' then value
                when t.from = 'Angela' then - value
           end) as diff
from table.trans t
where country = 'UK' and 'Angela' in (t.to, t.from);
```

Comment: Hi @gordon, thanks for your answer. Could you clarify what is the role of the last condition?
i.e. ```'Angela' in (t.to, t.from)``` given that it's already used in the sum case?

Comment: @AdamB. . . . It simply reduced the amount of data being aggregated.  So, it is not needed to get the right results.  It is a performance thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF as well

```
select SUM(if(transactions.from = 'Angela',ifnull(value,0),0)+ if(transactions.to = 'Angela',ifnull(-value,0),0)) diff
    from table.trans as transactions
    where country= 'UK' 
    and  'Angela' in (transactions.from,transactions.to)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you clarify what is the role of the last condition? i.e. ```'Angela' in (transactions.from,transactions.to)``` given that it's already used in the sum if?

Comment: You can ignore it of course but the advantage of adding this is it will reduce the set of data that you are searching for and thus the cost will reduce.